# Modifying Windows 7 Calculator

Tags: windows, windows-7, calculator

Hi does anyone know if it is possible to modify the Windows 7 calculator?  I would like to create either a new worksheet or a new view.  Anyone have good info or links for doing this, if it is even possible?

Comment: I'm sure this isn't possible. You'll just have to write your own. Calculators are pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

[You cannot extend calculator.](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/create-custom-template-worksheet-for-win7/21ac5eeb-90fc-4c98-b0f8-8f95d139d069)

i would use Excel; trying to write your own calculator is pretty difficult.